# PDO mysqli query, making an admin page and might need a variable column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've started making an admin page and want to have a form to edit the data in a database that dynamically presents the data for a user to edit.

But I am getting an error when the user selects what column they want. I could hard code the column names in and if they change in the database then I'll change it in the script, but would be nice to have it auto update so I wouldn't have to. Any help would be very appreciated.

**HTML**

```
     <form action="" method="POST">
     <label>Customer to edit
     <select name="id" >
       <option value="1">person1</option>
       <option value="2">person2</option>  
       <?php      // will get data dynamically ?> 
     </select>
     </label><br/>
     <label> Column to change
       <select name="column">
       <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
       <option value="lastname">lastname</option>      
       </select>  
       </label><br/>
       <label> Value to replace
       <input type="text" name="value"></input>
       </label><br/> 
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Edit"/>
     </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE booking SET :columname = :value WHERE id = :id');
 $stmt->execute(array(
    ':columnname' => $_POST['column'],
    ':id'   => $_POST['id'],
        ':value' => $_POST['value']
    ));
   }
```

**The error is:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDEC 2013\admin.php:154 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CDEC 2013\admin.php(154): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDEC 2013\admin.php on line 154
```

**line154** is   `':value' => $_POST['value']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use parameters to specify names of database objects (i.e. tables, columns).  You will need to manually concatenate the field name into the SQL you are forming for the prepared statement.  Make sure to escape the value since it won't be parametrized.

When you think about how prepared statements work, this makes sense, as the database has no way to prepare an execution plan when it does not know what tables and/or fields might be involved.

Comment: That does make sense, thank you. I will have a look into manually concatenating them. Didnt know the answer would be so simple but it answers my question. ty :)